# check checkbox by clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I got a problem with checking checkboxes by clicking a separate button. For example I want to check the Mercedes SLK checkbox by clicking the button unterneath. How can I implement that?

Thanks in advance for your feedbacks.

Example code:

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="volvo">Volvo XC90<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bmw">BMW 325i<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK
</form>
<button type="button">Check Mercedes SLK</button>
```

Comment: Have you done any minimal research into how to create forms in html?

Comment: <select> is not a checkbox, and your <input> is not a button. What are you trying to do exactly here...?

Comment: <form action="#">
     <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle" name="vehicle"             
      value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK
      <button type="button" id="checkMercedes"
    onclick="document.getElementById('vehicle').checked=true;">
     Check Mercedes SLK</button>     
</form>

Comment: @TechnoCracker - I believe this has been discussed in answers. Also getElementById does not work in many browsers UNLESS there is an ID

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
$("select[name='cars'] option[value='mercedes']").prop('checked', true)
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/118/)

just take this inside button click.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your button element:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('mercedes').checked = true"
```

Comment: It is poor practice to rely on side effects when there are actual methods to get named objects - does not work in FX 31 nor chrome 37 http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lges8jpu/

Answer (score 0):

Wthout changing the html and giving IDs which in itself would be a good idea.

Plain JS:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.querySelector("button").onclick=function() {
    document.getElementsByName("vehicle")[2].checked=true;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/z53xL7ps/)

```
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click",function() {
    $("input[value='mercedes']").prop("checked",true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using jquery like that:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="volvo">Volvo XC90<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bmw">BMW 325i<br> 
<input type="checkbox" id="slk" name="vehicle" value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK
</form>
<button id="checkSlk" type="button">Check Mercedes SLK</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#checkSlk").on("click", function () {
            if ($("#slk").is(':checked')) {
                $("#slk").attr("checked", false);
            } else {
                $("#slk").attr("checked", true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Pure JavaScript Solution For You -**

```js
function selectVehicleCheckboxByValue(valueData) {
    if(document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="vehicle"][value="'+valueData+'"]').checked !== true){
        document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="vehicle"][value="'+valueData+'"]').checked = true;
    }else{
        document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="vehicle"][value="'+valueData+'"]').checked = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="volvo">Volvo XC90<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bmw">BMW 325i<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="selectVehicleCheckboxByValue('volvo')">Volvo XC90</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="selectVehicleCheckboxByValue('bmw')">BMW 325i</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="selectVehicleCheckboxByValue('mercedes')">Check Mercedes SLK</button>
```